# Having trouble calculating the value of a list of classes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add all the values from the class "q-total" But I can't get it to work. Here's the code:

```
$(document).on("change", ".row-inputs", function(){
var total = 0;
var price = 0;
var multi = 0;


$('.q-quantity', this).each(function(){
    multi = $(this).val();
})

$(".q-price", this).each(function(){
    price += +$(this).val() * multi;
})

$(".q-total", this).val(price);

for (var i = 0; i < $(".q-total").length; i++) {
    // total = 0;
    // console.log($(".q-total", this).val() )
    total += parseInt($(".q-total", this).val());
}

console.log("Total " + total)

})
```

Below is the class code I use to add new rows to the html. In case this might help to figure out why the above code is not working.

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 10;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " 
inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.className = "row-inputs";
          newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='' 
          placeholder='product name' class='q-product-name'> " + 
          "<input type='number' name='' placeholder='0' class='q-quantity' 
          value=1> " +
          "<input type='text' name='' placeholder='price' class='q-price'> " 
          +
          "<input type='text' name='' placeholder='price' class='q-total'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What is it doing that isn't correct? Do you get a wrong value? Does it throw an error?

Comment: No, not an error. But the total it's not the same as if you add all the values manually. For example: 3 rows of 3, 4 and 5 would be 12. But instead the app gives me 15.

Comment: Add your HTML, please

Comment: I would recommend printing out the value when adding it to the total. You can also inspect the html and see if the values are correct there.

Comment: added a JSFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is incorrect:

**Change**

```
for (var i = 0; i < $(".q-total").length; i++) {
    // total = 0;
    // console.log($(".q-total", this).val() )
    total += parseInt($(".q-total", this).val());
}
```

**To**

```
  $(".q-total").each(function(){
    total += +$(this).val();
  })
```

In the original `for` loop you never iterate over the values, you always take `$(this).val()`. Not sure why you varied from your `.each()` approach you've used everywhere else, but that is your fix.

To explain further, using your example of add rows with prices of 3,4,5. The first time through (1st row), you have one element in the jQuery collection, so `total=0` becomes `total += 3`; Second row added and you have two elements, but only look at the value of the current row, so `total=0` becomes `total += 4` && `total += 4` hence `total=8`; On third row change, there are three elements, to `total = 15` ( 3 * 5);